# Find any value not equal to X in Elasticsearch arrays

Tags: elasticsearch

I want to build a query that matches any document that has any value in a multi-value field that does not equal a given value.

Index some documents

```
POST /example/type
{"array": ["a", "b", "c"]} <--- 1
{"array": ["d", "e", "x"]} <--- 2
{"array": ["x"]}           <--- 3
```

I want to build a query that says "match any document that has any value in array that does not equal x. In the above example that would match (1) and (2) since both of those contain at least one non "x" value. Document (3) would be rejected because it only contains "x".

I've tried the boolean must_not and query DSL NOT (!) operators but they work on an exclusion principle instead of a logical negated equality, and thus only return document (1).

I should add that performance is critical here so script based solutions will likely not work.

Answer (score 0):

Lucene index (which is what ElasticSearch is built upon) does not have a notion of original order of the values in your array. Moreover, Arrays of objects do not work as you would expect: you cannot query each object independently of the other objects in the array.

I believe script based solution is the only way to go

Or alternatively while indexing the docuemnts you can add additional parameter "length"

```
PUT my_test
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "array": {
        "type": "keyword"
      },
      "count":{
        "type": "integer"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Now search for docs where **not** (count==1 and array contains a)

```
GET /my_test/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must_not": [
        {
          "term": {
            "count": 1
          }
        },
        {
          "term": {
            "array": "x"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Then how are phrase queries with slop implemented. Order and size seem to be used for those queries.

Comment: phrase queries work for mapping type = text....for the array field ur defining i believe mapping type = keyword ......field keyword are not passed through analyzer

Comment: I mean, yeah, but it can obviously handle ordinals at some level...